# Vite and React for production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, vite

I'm using Vite and React.
I want to use different api when I use Production and Development, for do that I have this configuration:

```
// vite.config.js

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

const baseUrl = process.env.BASE_URL || "http://localhost:3001";


export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  const isProd = mode === "production";

  const config = {
    plugins: [react()],
    resolve: {
      alias: [{ find: "@", replacement: "/src" }],
      mainFields: []
    },
    server: {
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: isProd ? baseUrl : 'http://localhost:3001',
          changeOrigin: true,        
        },
      },
    },
  };

  return config;
});
```

My package.json

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build --mode production",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
```

To try it I use Docker, my image is:

```
FROM node:17-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm i
ARG BASE_URL='https://my-api.dev'
ENV BASE_URL=$BASE_URL
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

And start with:

```
docker run -p 80:80 react-app-prod
```

When I try to login I got 405 Method not allowed, so I presume that the application doesn't use the BASE_URL.

I tried even with serve, with `serve dist` but I have the same problem, I can't figure out with endpoint the application is going to call.

I don't have problem with dev env

**UPDATE**
I'm trying to understand why I got the error, I changed my vite configuration like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { loadEnv } from 'vite'
import http from "https";

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {

  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');
  
  const config = {
    plugins: [react()],
    resolve: {
      alias: [{ find: "@", replacement: "/src" }],
      mainFields: []
    },
    server: {
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: 'https://localhost:3001',
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: false,
          agent: new http.Agent()
        },
      },
    },
  };

  return config;
});
```

I'm trying to call localhost even in prod env but I get 404.
I'm using serve to try it. It's hard to check which url react calls, When I use proxy

Comment: Have you tried using `--build-arg`?

Comment: I have the same problem without Docker

Comment: Are you setting `BASE_URL` in your environment before running the build? `"build": "BASE_URL=foo vite build --mode production"`